# Iphone 3GS rendering different from 3G?

Tags: iphone, browser, cross-browser

Has anyone run into an issue with the iPhone 3GS rendering things different in their browsers than an iPhone 3G??  I am being told that is happening, although I find it hard to believe.

Thanks

Comment: Geometrically different?  Or could this observations just be the result of something like differences in the color temperature and brightness of the display between different production runs?

Answer (score 1):

Are they on the same OS release? That sounds like a more likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The 3G and 3GS use different GPUs. The 3G uses the PowerVR MGX GPU versus the 3GS/4 using the SGX GPU.

Comment: But everything looks fine in my iPhone4 which you say has the same GPU as the 3GS, so still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Then ask for a screenshot of the problem. Instruct the user to press home + wake buttons at the same time, then get the image off the camera roll to you. We can't guess as to what's going on with any level of accuracy. Show us what it looks like on your 4, and what they're seeing if you still need help.